# Phone number algorithm

Tags: combinatorics

If a phone number were turned into an equation, how difficult would it be to reverse engineer the original phone number ? How many potential (10 digit, North American) phone numbers could a solution be narrowed down to?

That is to say if:

`1 (555) 123-4567` became `1 * 555 * 123 - 4567 = 63698`

or

`1 * A * B - C = D`,

how many potential values for A, B & C could be produced from any value D?

`63698 = 1 * ? * ? - ?`

Given: The number originates in the USA, and thereby conforms to the North American Numbering Plan (NXX-NXX-XXXX,where N is any digit 2-9 and X is any digit 0-9).From this we know A and B to be a subset of 3 digit numbers and C to be a 4 digit number.

What approaches would be best when thinking about this problem?

Comment: You specifically want to multiply the first three numbers, and subtract the last one?

Comment: @JackM Yes, that's the general idea. Yet given a US number, the first digit is always `1` and for all intents & purposes can be ignored, so you really only have to worry about 2 multiplicands.

Comment: For clarification purposes: where did this question come from?  Are you looking for an approximate answer, or an exact average, or an exact answer for every case?

Comment: An exact answer seems incredibly difficult. First of all, $AB$ could take on any of $10\space000$ values, and for each of those we have to establish how many decompositions into two factors they have within the specified range. This is going to be related to the prime factorization of all of those $10\space000$ values, and we all know how lovely and predictable prime numbers are...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It came from me looking at a phone number and thinking "What if that were an equation? Those parenthesis could be multiplication. Hmm...." Then I got curious if the resulting number from said equation was unique enough to be utilized for something useful e.g. a hashkey or password given that the formula for computing it is easy enough for a human to remember.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it seems to me there are 800 possible values for A (minus those starting 0 or 1), ditto for B. That's 800^2. Divide by 2 based on commutativity: (800^2) = 320,000. Then of those numbers, look for ones that are D +-9999. Count em up and there is your answer. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max hash value of a phone number is (approximately) $1000\cdot 1000-0=10^6$. The min hash value is $100\cdot 100-10000=0$. The number of legal phone numbers is $8^210^8=6.4\cdot 10^9$.  This means that (on average) approximately $\frac{6.4\cdot 10^9}{10^6}=6400$ phone numbers correspond to one hash value. I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it is a reasonable first approximation I think. Thus, there are $6400$ triples $(A,B,C)$ on average for each hash value.

Answer (score 1):

I might get railed for this one, but just compute it for all possible values.

You'd only need to compute the cases for which $A \geq B$ (say) because multiplication is commutative.

So compute all of the products $AB$ that you need ($A \geq B$), and organize them in a histogram with bin size of $1$.  If $A \neq B$, count it twice.  Then copy this histogram $9999$ more times, displacing one copy apiece each of $1$ to $9999$ places to the left, and add them all up.

Comment: Note that this commutativity means that it's impossible to uniquely determine a number in almost all cases, because A and B *can* be swapped without affecting the result; there would never be any differentiating (653) 441-0291 from (441) 563-0291.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the question that's looking for an answer: For a given value of $D$, how many distinct triples $A,B,C$ can this represent?

Answer (score 1):

The code is available at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EZX9ytjX).

Top ten excluding 0-99 from A and B:

```
22854 at 4677
22854 at 5337
22852 at 5302
22852 at 5303
22852 at 5304
22852 at 5340
22852 at 5343
22852 at 5344
22850 at 4161
22850 at 4162
```

Top ten excluding 0-199 from A and B:

```
16021 at 193853
16021 at 193854
16021 at 193905
16021 at 193857
16021 at 195209
16021 at 193855
16020 at 195243
16020 at 195210
16019 at 195206
16019 at 193851
```

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Given D, I would loop $n$ from $0$ to $9999$, factor $D+n$ then look for ways to split the factors to make acceptable numbers. Note that $D$ has to be at least $200^2-9999=30001$ if I wanted the $D$ that yielded the most choices, I would fill an array with the number of representations of numbers from $30001$ to $999^2$ and then find the span of $10000$ with the highest total.